# Some issue with login credentials in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

Below is my code for making a user login the page but when I tried to submit the form it does not check database and directly gives me the `else` output i.e invalid ID or password I am not getting any error reports too though error reporting is turned on I am not sure where am I going wrong here.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit'])=='Login')
    {
        $email=$_POST['emaillogin'];
        $pass=$_POST['passlogin'];
        $pass=md5($pass);

        $email = stripslashes($email);
        $pass = stripslashes($pass);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

        require_once "database.php";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE email = '$email' and password='$pass'";
        $loginresult=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($loginresult);
        $rowcnt=mysql_num_rows($loginresult);
        if($rowcnt==1)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
            $_SESSION['mobile']=$row['mobile'];
            $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
            $_SESSION['lname']=$row['lname'];
            echo "  <script>
                        window.location = '../';
                    </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "  <script>
                        alert('Invalid Login ID or Password....');
                        window.location = '../';
                    </script>";
        }
```

I've even tried to echo wheather I am getting email and password properly from form and yes I was getting but issue starts from below line I guess:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE email = '$email' and password='$pass'";`

**EDIT:FORM ADDED BELOW**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" name="emaillogin" required>
    <input type='password' id='password' name='passlogin' placeholder='Password here' required>
    <input type="submit" id="continuesubmitemail" name="loginsubmit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: first try to print the value of $sql and tell what it is printing

Comment: before checking isset() try to print_r($_POST) and tell what it is printing

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal as **OP** write in question that `output i.e invalid ID or password ` it means code not enter into `if condition`

Comment: ok then what is the value of $sql

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal This is the value of `$sql`

`SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE email = 'admin@admin.com' and password='e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is used to check variable is set or not

You can check your condition as

```
 if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit']) && $_POST['loginsubmit']=='Login')
```

Also write `session_start();` at the top of your page

Use while loop to get data

```
 $rowcnt=mysql_num_rows($loginresult);
        if($rowcnt==1)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($loginresult))
            {
            $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
            $_SESSION['mobile']=$row['mobile'];
            $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
            $_SESSION['lname']=$row['lname'];
            }
            echo "  <script>
                        window.location = '../';
                    </script>";
        }
```

And finally stop using `mysql` it is deprecated . You can use `PDO or mysqli`

Answer (score 2):

how can you even get into that line? `isset function returns boolean` and it will be always false because you are doing it like:

```
if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit'])=='Login')
```

you should make it like:

```
 if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit']) && $_POST['loginsubmit']=='Login')
```

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` returns true or false so you have to write your if condition below..

```
    if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit']) && $_POST['loginsubmit']=='Login')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_query($sql) OR DIE(mysql_error());`
this will display your mysql error
`ps , mysql` is deprecated , use `mysqli or pdo instead`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your condition

with

```
if($_POST['loginsubmit']=='Login')
```

Comment: Please add more text, perhaps explanation. Your answer is currently being voted for deletion. You should do so to avoid future misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $loginresult=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and check that are you getting any output